# How to fetch all data after adding new data in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code for adding person object in firebase.

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Person");


    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating Person object
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(name);
            person.setAddress(address);
            new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL).child("Person").push().setValue(person);
        }
    });

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Getting the data from snapshot
                Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                //Adding it to a string
                String string = "Name: " + person.getName() + "\nAddress: " + person.getAddress() + "\n\n";

                //Displaying it on textview
                textViewPersons.setText(string);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Adding data is working fine and every add creating a new key for person.

But addValueEventListener is showing me only last added entry. I want all the entries data.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Did you check if you were replacing all `myRef`'s content with the new Person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time anything changes in the `Person` node, you get notified through `onDataChange()`. In there you loop over the people and then for each call:

```
textViewPersons.setText(string);
```

So you're constantly replacing the contents of the text view with the information from each person. After each loop it will end up showing just the information for the last user. You can easily see that the code loops through all people by adding:

```
System.out.println(string);
```

With this you'll see each person in logcat, but only the last person in the text view.

One solution is to either use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, both of which handle lists of items. Another (quicker to implement) way to show all users it to append the strings in the text view:

```
textViewPersons.setText(textViewPersons.getText()+string+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps:

```
String dataviewer=new String();

Firebase firebase=new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

        //Creating Person object
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(name);
        person.setAddress(address);
        new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL).child("Person").push().setValue(person);
    }
});

  firebase.child("Person").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        // Retrieve values as they are added to Firebase
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {

            Map<String,Object> vals=(Map<String,Object>)snapshot.getValue();
            String name_person=String.valueOf(vals.get("name"));
            String address_person=String.valueOf(vals.get("address"));
            dataviewer+="Name: " + name_person + "\nAddress: " + address_person + "\n\n";
            }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```